# Office Ribbon resizing

Tags: vba, ms-office, ribbon

I am trying to define a ribbon for an Excel VBA Addin, with tabs, groups and buttons.  It all works OK.  This is done with a CustomUI like process (I actually have a script that zips and unzips).

However, if the window is narrowed, then entire groups just disappear (together with their keyboard shortcuts!).  What I would like is that the labels disappear first, just leaving the icons, as happens on, for example, the Home tab in Excel.

There is some confusing documentation, but no complete example.  I am also confused about the relationship between Office Ribbon, WPF.Net ribbon, Dynamics ribbon, and Windows Ribbons.  I suspect they are unrelated tools.

Any pointers to an example most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

After many red herrings, found it.  Put

```
<group ... autoScale ="true">
```

on all group elements.  Does not work for Excel 2007 (which is why I use a script to generate variants of ribbons for different versions of Excel).

BTW.  Excel > Options > Advanced > General > Show addin errors needs to be checked in order to see ribbon errors.

As to my second part, it looks like there are several different unrelated implementations of the Ribbon, which makes the docs hard to find.